# JNI style signature of the method

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How do you generate the JNI style signature of a method? I need it as a parameter to this particular class's function sendMessage(...):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/IJavaObject.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `javap -s`. You can do it by hand following the rules in the JNI Specification but at best you will only come up with what `javap -s` would have told you in seconds and at worst you will get it wrong and have a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Do I need to download anything special to get that command to work? My shell doesn't seem to find that command.

Comment: I downloaded JDK7 and found the command in the bin folder, but now it doesn't identify the filepath to my class...

Comment: @Matt It works exactly the same way as the `java` command. The class has to be on the classpath. I don't know how you were planning to develop in Java without a JDK ;-)

Comment: That's weird because java and javac worked fine, I already had a JDK, but javap didn't work for it... so I downloaded a new one and I'm trying to run javap directly giving the filepath to the bin folder (it won't run anywhere else, or like by itself). I might be doing something really stupid...

Comment: @Matt `javap -classpath <classpath> -s package.package.classname`. Exactly the same as `java`.